# How can I fully remove title and authors in ACM template, including whitespace

Tags: acm, author, acmart

My university recommends to use the acmart document class for theses, while at the same time requiring a standard cover page which includes title and author information. Considering I am also limited in the number of pages, I do not want to repeat this information on the first page of the thesis. When I leave the title and author information out, \maketitle prompts a "no title given" exception, but extra whitespace is still reserved on the first page. Moreover, when I omit \maketitle, the ACM formatting doesn't work. Unfortunately, my coding skills are fairly weak. Would anyone know a way to get around this?

Thank you in advance,

R

Comment: Which acmart format do you use?  sigconf, sigchi, acmtog...?

Comment: Hi Boris, I am using sigconf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help Boris!

If any other beginner encouters this issue, here is the full answer:

Replace `\maketitle` with `\twocolumn`

Not using `\maketitle` disables the commands:

```
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\keywords{}
```

However, this can be easily solved by substituting them for `\section*{abstract}` and `\section*{keywords}` in the body of the document.

Answer (score 1):

What you need from `\maketitle` is just `\twocolumn` command.  Add it to your document like this:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]